# Having an issue with OCMS snippets

Tags: octobercms, octobercms-plugins, october-partial

Currently, I'm trying to turn a navbar partial into a snippet, and have certain buttons or etc be editable via front-end without much effort.I've set up the snippet and posted it to the content section of my homepage.

The pages plugin itself detects the tables I have set up on the partial and the values, but when I try to access them using `{{ varName }}` it doesn't work.

I have tested the snippet itself to see if it does not work by manually setting it in the code itself with `{{ varName|default('value') }}` and that works fine. I am using menu items along side the snippets but they won't interact in any way aside from being part of the same navbar.

I'm unsure if I'm missing something I have been messing around with this for a few days since I'm new to October CMS so I do apologize if I've missed something really small.

```
[viewBag]
snippetCode = "navbar"
snippetName = "NavBar"
snippetProperties[telNumber][title] = "varName"
snippetProperties[telNumber][type] = "string"
snippetProperties[telNumber][default] = "Value"
snippetProperties[telNumber][options][] = ""
snippetProperties[bookLink][title] = "varName"
snippetProperties[bookLink][type] = "string"
snippetProperties[bookLink][default] = "Value"
snippetProperties[bookLink][options][] = ""
snippetProperties[bookText][title] = "varName"
snippetProperties[bookText][type] = "string"
snippetProperties[bookText][default] = "Value"
snippetProperties[bookText][options][] = ""
```